# BindingList и несколько combobox

Tags: c#, winforms

Подключаю bindingList список combobox. Рабочий код:

```
BindingList<Discipline> source = new BindingList<Discipline>(){};           

source.Add(new Discipline(methods.resultSelect.ResultData.Rows[i].ItemArray[4].ToString()                 
));             

combobox1.DisplayMember="short_name";
combobox1.ValueMember="cod_discipline";
combobox1.DataSource=source;
combobox1.SelectedItem=null;
```

Проблема в том, что если я этот список привязываю к 2 и более combobox, и начинаю изменять один из них, то соответственно меняется значение, отображаемое во всех combobox. Каким образом грамотно привязать список например к 10 combobox, чтобы значения не влияли друг на друга?

Comment: создать 10 `BindingList`?

Answer (score 1):

Решено добавлением этой строки перед привязкой:

```
 combobox1.BindingContext = new BindingContext();
 combobox1.DataSource=source;
```

Answer (score 0):

И хоть вы нашли сами решение, я бы предложил использовать для каждого комбобокса отдельный `BindingSource`.

```
BindingSource bs1 = new BindingSource();
BindingSource bs2 = new BindingSource();

bs1.DataSource = bindigList;
bs2.DataSource = bindigList;

_comboBox1.DataSource = bs1;
_comboBox2.DataSource = bs2;
```

`BindingSource` удобен тем, что в нем есть свойство `Current` -текущий выбранный элемент, и есть методы для движения по коллекции `MoveFirst()`, `MoveNext()` и т.д.